# Change NFSEN to poll and graph every 30 seconds

Tags: monitoring, perl, rrdtool

I am asked to modify a default clean `nfsen-1.3.6p1` install to to collect and poll every 30 seconds.

I "patched" `libexec/NfSenRC.pm`'s `nfdump` command arguments that it uses to `-w -D -t 30 -p $port -u $uid -g $gid $buffer_opts $subdirlayout -P $pidfile $ziparg $extensions` (`-t 30`) and the capture data is updated every 30 seconds but I don't know how and where to change the RRD resolution (yes I appreciate that the rrds will need recreating) and the way they're used.

Also changed other 300 second hardcoded values and `if` statements in the other modules in `libexec/`

And also how to change the web interface to allow display of all these changes, currently it still locks to at least 5 minutes ago when checking the most recent values in a graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it can be "patched" to do that and it does seem to work. The below achieves the aim but of course has lots of room for improvement such as exposing this as perhaps an installation directive and have many other tweaks.

In it's default install dir `/data/nfsen/` you have you find instances of the hardcoded 300 or sec steps, windows, slices etc, same for the occurrences in the web dir `/var/www/nfsen`

More notable changes are in `libexec/NfSenRRD.pm` to change the RRD create command
First the data sources definition changed to

`push @DS, "DS:$ds:ABSOLUTE:60:U:U";`

and below that to add the "step" argument for `rrdtool`

`RRDs::create ( $rrd_filename, "--start", $start, "--step", 30,` 
(The RRA parameters can be tweaked to your needs here too)

If you had .rrds created they need to be remade, you can do that by removing your capture definitions in the main config file, running `perl nfsen reconfig` then putting them back in.

in `libexec/NfSenRC.pm` the arguments for the `nfcapd` command need changing to
`my $common_args = "-w -D -t 30 -p $port -u $uid -g $gid $buffer_opts $subdirlayout -P $pidfile $ziparg $extensions";` (include `-t 30`)

For good measure I compiled the latest NFDUMP and pointed nfsen to the new binaries.

Now back in the webdir in `details.php` `$WinSizeScale` needs to be tweaked as well. Luckily those are well commented so you can work out what values to put to accommodate the hack.

Loads of room for improvement and customisation here too.